# What's wrong with this code to make it not add the divisors to sum each time?

Tags: java, numbers

I've beeen trying to get a program written for a lab for class, and I believe I almost have it, but it won't add up the divisors (div in the code) to the sum and return true if it is a perfect number and false otherwise. My code compiles and runs fine but will only return a false, presumably because sum is staying at 1 (it initializes at one since 1 is a divisor of every number). number is a private int brought in from the constructors and set statements.

```
  public boolean isPerfect()
  {
    int x = number -1 ;
    int div = 0;
    int sum = 1;
    while(x> 1)
    {
        if(number % x == 0)
        {
            div =  x;
            sum=+ div;
        }
        x--;
    }
    if(sum == number)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Get a debugger and debug.Hint method signature should be `isPerfect(int number)`

Comment: Where on earth are you getting your `number` variable from?

Comment: @Xymostech probably a `static` class variable. Shudders

Comment: my `number` is a private int that is class-wide:

`public class Perfect
{
   private int number;

 public Perfect()
 {
  
 }`
 
 `public Perfect(int num)
 {
  number = num;
 }`
 
 `public void setNum(int num)
 {
  number = num;
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the `+=` / `=+` issue, your code also says that 1 is a [perfect number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number), which is incorrect (6 is the first perfect number). This is because you start with a `sum` of 1, the loop won't execute at all, then you compare `sum` and `number`, which are equal for 1. You could just add a check for this special case, e.g.

```
if(sum == number && number > 1)...
```

Additional tip - instead of :

```
if(sum == number)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

You can just use:

```
return (sum == number);
```

Comment: Here's how I have my runner class set up: 

`public class Lab09h
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
  Perfect test = new Perfect(496);
  out.println(test);
  
  test.setNum(45);
  out.println(test);  
  
  test.setNum(6);
  out.println(test);
  
  test.setNum(14);
  out.println(test);
  
  test.setNum(8128);
  out.println(test);
  
  test.setNum(1245);
  out.println(test);
  
  test.setNum(33);
  out.println(test);
  
  test.setNum(28);
  out.println(test);
  
  test.setNum(27);
  out.println(test);
  
  test.setNum(33550336);
  out.println(test);
                
 }
}`

Comment: I just changed `int sum = 0;` and as I'm sure you mentioned, it is not a perfect number. However though, it then changes all my other results to say that they are not perfect

Comment: Yes, that's not the solution - see my answer for a suggestion.

Comment: yes it does.... however, your suggestion uses an if/else and the subject of these labs is to utilize while loops

Comment: Actually, I suggested eliminating one `if/else` from your answer, and adding a condition to an `if` that was already there ;-)

Comment: so instead of `if(sum == number)`... change it to `if(sum == number && number != 1)`

Comment: when I corrected my code to what you suggested, it is still saying zero is a perfect number, which it's not

Comment: Good point - have edited answer (use > 1 rather than != 1). It worked for my code because I had a different loop structure ;-)

Comment: just curious, what was the loop structure that you used when recreating my code?

Comment: Just a `for` loop rather than a `while`, and without the `div` variable, I think. I've deleted it now, unfortunately!

Comment: that was probably a more direct and simpler way to achieve the same result

Answer (score 3):

This is backwards.  `sum =+ div;` should be `sum += div;`

What you have is basically `sum = (+div)`, in other words positive `div`.

Comment: @jlordo Not always, but it is in this context.

Comment: when is it not the same? i cannot think of a counterexample.

Comment: @climbage i.e. when it causes an implicit cast that a lone `=` wouldn't? Still can't think of such a case.

Comment: wouldn't `=+` be a syntax error, if the right side would not be a primitive number?

Comment: Yep, that's why I said *in this context*.  In retrospect I should have just agreed since that was implied

Comment: This answer is correct, but there is an additional problem with the code - see my answer also...

Answer (score 0):

You could have   sum= sum + div;  or sum += div;

also where is your number variable define i guess it is something like public boolean isPerfect(int number)

Comment: it is:

   `public class Perfect
{
   private int number;

 public Perfect()
 {
  
 }
 
 public Perfect(int num)
 {
  number = num;
 }
 
 public void setNum(int num)
 {
  number = num;
 }`

Comment: and I thought about what you suggested in the top line of your answer when I was writing it but wanted to use `sum += div;` to avoid it seeming redundant in my mind.

Comment: if you think about it also you can use return (sum == number);  instead of your if else combination

Comment: the `if(sum == number)` never even crossed my mind although I'm sure I've been told that it is equally as useful from my teacher